# Excel: Sum total values that correspond with a value

Tags: excel

Does anyone know how to write a function that would write find any values that match this value, and then sum their corresponding values?

Using my image: http://postimg.org/image/6ygotfomv/

I want to create something that says, find all values within row P that match "1" and sum the corresponding values in Q.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

no need to write a function, just use

> Sumif(P:P, "=1", R:R)

see https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b for details

You can replace "1" bu the reference to a cell containing the value you want , and if you omit the third argument, the sum will be done on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your final cell

```
=SUMIF(P:P,"=1",Q:Q)
```

alternatively you could use:

```
=SUMIF(P:P,1,Q:Q)
```

but the earlier, will give you much more options for non number criteria